# Reportviewer VB.NET about Switch Expression

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc, reportviewer

Hello everyone can anyone correct my codes in rdlc tables

i have 1 tables and on that table there was a Field!ans1 that was computing for the average of the column(RED CIRCLE in IMAGE) then i want that average to filter to an if statement to identify if that average is Agree , disagree or Stronglyagree(BLACK CIRCLE IN THE IMAGE)

Here's the Picture of my RDLC Table 
the Black Circle is the If Statement that will identify if the Average Below in the Red Circle if is Agree,Disagree,or Strongly Agree
but i am having a problem because the statement always stock on Disagree even its value is 3

[image]

```
// Here is my Code in the Black Circle in the IMAGE
=Switch(Fields!ans1.Value < 1, "Strongly Disagree ",
Fields!ans1.Value > 2, " Disagree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 3, "Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 4, "Strongly Agree"
)

//Here is the Code in the RedCircle 
=Avg(CDbl(Fields!ans1.Value))
```

Comment: So from 1.6 to 2.4 is ignored?

Comment: I just entered "conditional statements in rdlc vb.net" into a search engine and 20 seconds later I was reading that you can use the `IIf` function, just like in regular VB.  If I can find an answer to your question is less than 30 seconds without ever having created an RDLC report myself, why can't you?  This site is not a substitute for a search engine. It's the place you ask a question when you have tried everything you can for yourself first. A web search is something you should be doing for yourself without even thinking about it. Of course, don't search for "how to knit cat jumpers".

Comment: actually i tried ways like this 
=iif(Avg(CDbl(Fields!ans1.Value >= 3.6, Iif(Fields!ans1.Value >= 2.4, "Strongly Agree", "Agree"))

but its not working

Comment: I must have missed where you said that in your question.  Please provide ALL the relevant information. The code you have tried that doesn't work is ALWAYS relevant.  Please update your question and provide what you think is the correct code AND what happens when you try it, i.e. error message(s) and/or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: question updated sir :) sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a switch statement of any kind is evaluated top-down.  Is 3.00 greater than 2?  Yes it is, so the result is " Disagree" (why you haven't noticed and removed that rogue space, I don't know).  If you are going to compare using the 'greater than' operator then you need to compare the largest value first this:

```vb
=Switch(Fields!ans1.Value < 1, "Strongly Disagree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 4, "Strongly Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 3, "Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 2, "Disagree"
)
```

should work.  That's just basic logic that you should have learned in maths class. Note that I have removed that rogue space too.

By the way, that is still going to ignore any values in the range 1.0 - 2.0.

Comment: but how it will work i tried this one but as you said 1.0 - 2.0 is not working

=Switch(Fields!ans1.Value > 4 , "Strongly Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 3.5, "Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 2.6, "Disagree",
Fields!ans1.Value < 1, "Strongly Disagree"
)

Comment: Well, the first thing you would do is decide what the actual conditions are that you want to implement.  Then, if you want us to help you implement them, it might be helpful to tell us what those rules are.  That said, I've shown you how to implement this type of rule so you already know what to do.  You just have to engage your brain and do it.

Comment: more clear problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875965/putting-remarks-above-average-score-in-table-in-rdlc