# Putting Remarks above Average Score in Table in RDLC

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

Hi i am trying to Compute the Average Score of all the evaluators and put the Remarks above the total average and i used Switch Statement to check it. if the Average Score is Strongly Agree,Agree,Disagree or Strongly Disagree

i think there is a problem in my Switch statement code please help the remarks is not accurate

[Here is The Picture of my Reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93g74.jpg)

The Fields!ans1. Value have the average score

Here is my code in Determining if the remarks of Average Score is Agree,Strongly Agree or Disagree

```
  =Switch(
Fields!ans1.Value < 1.50, "Strongly Disagree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 1.74, "Disagree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 2.74, "Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 3.74, "Strongly Agree"

    )
```

Comment: Please? 

Comment: You have completely ignored what I told you in answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133770/reportviewer-vb-net-about-switch-expression).  I told you to compare to the largest value first when using the `>` operator and you haven't done so.  I pointed out that there was a gap in the range that you were testing for and you still have one.  Why bother asking questions if you're going to ignore the answers?

Comment: Sir . i did what you say , i try that code , actually im trying again what you said.

=Switch(

Fields!ans1.Value > 3.74, "Strongly Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 2.74, "Agree",
Fields!ans1.Value > 1.74, "Disagree",
Fields!ans1.Value < 1, "Strongly Disagree"
    )

but when the value of my Fields!ans1.Value is 2.5 > they put Strongly Agree ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVE ! . i used ReportItems!Textbox.Value instead of the Fields!ans1.value